# Difference between a listener with no <filter> and one with <filter type=""/>

Tags: wcf, configuration, filter, resharper, trace

I've seen many examples where a `<source>` node has been setup in `<System.Diagnostics>` in configuration files for tracing like so:

```
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <clear/>
      <add name="SharedListener">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
```

Is there any difference between that and removing the `<filter>` node:

```
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <clear/>
      <add name="SharedListener"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
```

and if so, what? It's not a big deal except the extra lines of code and Resharper's solution-wide analysis complaining about an empty `type` attribute.

Comment: Just a little note - ReSharper 7 is not complaining anymore about empty type attribute of filter tag.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the note. Time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, except fewer lines of XML.